# Cannot convert String to Builder Class Error while implementing builder Pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

Cannot convert String to Builder Class Error while implementing builder Pattern. Please let me know what i am doing wrong and where. Thanks.

package BuilderDesignPattern;

public class Employee {

```
private final int id;
private String Name;
private String Address;

private Employee(EmployeeBuilder empB){
```

// Getting error at this line type mismatch cannot convert string to Employee.EmployeeBuilder.

```
    this.id = empB.getId();
    this.Name = empB.getName();
    this.Address = empB.getAddress();

}

public static class EmployeeBuilder{

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    public EmployeeBuilder setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
    public EmployeeBuilder setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }
    public EmployeeBuilder setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
        return this;
    }
    public EmployeeBuilder getId() {
        return this;
    }
    public EmployeeBuilder getName() {
        return this;
    }
    public EmployeeBuilder getAddress() {
        return this;
    }

    public Employee build(){

        return new Employee(this);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Code section has lines outside. Please fix for a better question

Comment: I've never seen a pattern where the object to be built takes the builder in parameter... The builder builds something, it is his job (an evolued factory). The object to be built does not know anything about the builder (do your car keep a trace of the machine that was used to build it? - no, but the opposite could be true)

Comment: @spi, you haven't read [Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2), where Josh Bloch popularized the Builder pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getters are wrong and not returning the right fields. It should be like this:

```
public int getId() {
    return this.Id;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.Name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return this.Address;
}
```

P.S.: In java there is a convention to name fields with lowercase.

P.S.2: This is not a first-class builder as the class built "knows" about builder.

Comment: @spi you're right. But that's where the exception comes from;>

Comment: @Andronicus I didn't get your second point "This is not a first-class builder as the class built "knows" about builder"  Could you please explain it.

Comment: The class that you're building shouldn't take a builder as a parameter.

Comment: @Andronicus Could you please share an example for this?

Comment: @PriyankaTaneja here's an example: https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern. If you find this answer helpful, consider marking as correct

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: The class you're building should absolutely take its builder as a parameter. That's exactly what's shown in [Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2), where Josh Bloch popularized the pattern. The alternative is either a constructor that takes too many arguments, or mutable fields, which is what the builder pattern is meant to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Your getters should not return `this`.

It should return the attributes.

```java
public class EmployeeBuilder{

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private String Address;

    public EmployeeBuilder setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeBuilder setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeBuilder setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeBuilder getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public EmployeeBuilder getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public EmployeeBuilder getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public Employee build(){
        return new Employee(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: A Builder should not have getters. That's what the item it builds is for.